# How do you know that public Docker images are secure?

Tags: security, docker

I'm just getting started with Docker, and I see that there are lots of images available at the [docker hub repository](https://registry.hub.docker.com/). It seems like the normal way to set up a new docker container is to copy one of these images and go from there. But how do I know that these containers don't have malicious code in them, or that they don't compromise my security in some other way?

For instance but how do I know that the OS in the container isn't (for example) capturing keystrokes if I ssh into it, or hijacking system resources for some other purpose?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/39974069/7005167

Answer (score 4):

The images marked as "Trusted build" are built by Docker on their server from the sources given by the user. You can easily check the Dockerfile from where the image have been built to check for malicious code.

You also have the 'official' images (those that does not start with 'somthing/') that are officially supported by Docker. If you trust Docker, inc, you can trust those image.

For the third part images, not from a trusted build and not from Docker, then you can check the history with `docker history <image>` (after pulling it) to see how it has been built, but common sense applies. It cannot be trusted.

Docker is working of provenance, so we should soon see CA Certificates check and proof of origin. Until then, just be careful are use only trusted build that you checked or official images.

Comment: Also, regarding your particular concern of keylogger, you can easily check for this by looking at 'docker inspect <image>'. This can be trusted as this will be executed by docker. You need to check the 'ENTRYPOINT' and 'CMD' fields. If one of those is a keylogger, then you know. Otherwise, you are good. (Unless of course if it starts a script, in case you need to check. A keylogger can be obfuscated). If you start bash, you are sure there is nothing as bash will be the only process running.